# android error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

i get user reports that the app crash
in the online console i find several crash logs like

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service
com.chris.mydays.UpdateWidgets@428eb2d8 with null:
java.lang.NullPointerException at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2555)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:139) at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException at
com.chris.mydays.UpdateWidgets.onStart(UpdateWidgets.java:50) at
android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450) at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2538)
... 10 more
```

any idea whats about and i can do?

thanks
chris

Comment: Something is assigned to `NULL` at `com.chris.mydays.UpdateWidgets.onStart(UpdateWidgets.java:50)`

Comment: It will be nice if you share your code especialy where your null pointer is thrown.

Comment: Holy crap this from the my days app that my ex girlfriend used to track all that awesome girl stuff. Golden. If the widget is updating from a server side call my guess could be that it's not getting data that you're expecting it to have

Comment: @JakeWilson801 Wrong color.

Comment: @jakeWilson801.. right its MyDays :) hope it worked for ur ex. and no, its nothing loaded from a server side

Comment: @dave newton: ? what u mean by Wrong Color?
I am quiet bad in reading Error Logs :)

Comment: @wawek... will check and if needed come back to u

Comment: 49   Bundle extras;
50   if ((extras = intent.getExtras()) != null) {

i even check at line 50 if its null

Answer (score 1):

I think the most significant lines are these two:

> com.chris.mydays.UpdateWidgets.onStart(UpdateWidgets.java:50) at
>   android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450) at

So I'd open your `UpdateWidgets.java` file and go to line 50, which should be in a `Service` in the `onStartCommand()` method.

Comment: 49   Bundle extras;
50   if ((extras = intent.getExtras()) != null) {

i even check at line 50 if its null

Comment: But if it's null you're first assigning and then comparing (precedence priorities). So if it's null this will throw an exception. I'd first compare and once I've checked it's not null, then assign.

Comment: Can't you check whether Intent is null? How did you get it?

Comment: Of course he can, that's exactly what I'm saying! But in his code he's doing two operations within a single line: a comparation and an assignation, and that's where the danger is. If the intent is null, he's assigning something that doesn't exist, that's why I recommended checking first and assigning then.